# NullPointerException in Query.list() with hibernate hql query

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I'm getting a weird exception on a hql query i'm not really prepared to face. The query gets written properly (I can see it in debug) and it was working properly this morning, so i don't get what i'm missing here. Is it a problem of the query? The code is below:

```
@Override
public ServerPaginatedResponse<Entity1> getEntityByEntity(int id) {

    String hql = "from Entity1 p ";
    hql += "join p.Entity2 u ";
    hql += "where u.id =:id";
    Query query = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    log.debug("hql : " + query.toString());

    ServerPaginatedResponse<Entity1> entity1List = new ServerPaginatedResponse<Entity1>();
    List<Entity1> list = new ArrayList<Entity1>();
    try {
        list = query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Entity1.class) ).list();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        log.error(e1.getMessage(), e1);
    }
    entity1List.setStartRow(0);
    entity1List.setEndRow(list.size());
    entity1List.setData(list);
    return entity1List;
}
```

The error is thrown by this line:

```
list = query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Entity1.class) ).list();
```

And it is a `NullPointerException`, but the query is set rightly i can see it in debug. Where can the problem be?

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR com.sgss.nove.domain.dao.profile.impl.ProfileDAO - null
[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.initialize(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:112)
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.hql.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:96)
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultList(QueryLoader.java:423)
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
[ERROR]     at com.sgss.nove.domain.dao.profile.impl.ProfileDAO.getProfilesByUser(ProfileDAO.java:94)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
[ERROR]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.getProfilesByUser(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at com.sgss.nove.service.profile.impl.ProfileManager.getProfileByUser(ProfileManager.java:78)
[ERROR]     at com.sgss.nove.server.profile.ProfileManagerWebImpl.getProfileByUser(ProfileManagerWebImpl.java:108)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
[ERROR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
[ERROR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
[ERROR]     at com.sgss.nove.UserSessionControlFilter.doFilter(UserSessionControlFilter.java:130)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
[ERROR]     at com.sgss.nove.GWTCacheControlFilter.doFilter(GWTCacheControlFilter.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: try to add full stacktrace

Comment: `query.setResultTransformer` return `this`. And we know `query` isn't null, since you used a method on it before. Can it be `Transformers.aliasToBean(Entity1.class)` throwing the exception?

Comment: the nullpointer exception is thrown even with 'query.list()' simple...

Comment: i'm adding the stacktrace

Comment: Would the `join` result of `Entity1` and `Entity2`, create `Entity1` entity?

Comment: yes it should there is a set of ENtity2 in Entity1 so they should be placed there do you think that this is the problem?

Comment: No compliments @Armaiti, the problem was there, i debugged better and i found it out. Thanks a lot!